# Query complaining about uniqueness violation when I know the record is unique

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on an application and adding usernames. So far, we have been relying on email only.

I am writing a query to generate usernames based on first and last names. When I run the query, I get an error about a uniqueness violation on the username column. However, when checking the record it complains about, I find that it is definitely unique. What am I missing?

The query:

```
WITH u2 AS (SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY first_name, last_name ORDER BY id ASC) AS row, first_name, last_name FROM users)
UPDATE users
  SET username = COALESCE(left(trim(u2.first_name),1), '')||COALESCE(replace(trim(u2.last_name), ' ', '_'), '')||(CASE WHEN u2.row > 1 THEN u2.row::varchar ELSE '' END)
  FROM u2
  WHERE users.id = u2.id;
```

Comment: Does u2 only have one row? You are trying to update from a non-scalar value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row number should be calculated on `username`, not on the pair `(first_name, last_name)` because of users which have the same last name and first names starting with the same letters, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name) VALUES
    ('John', 'Smith'),
    ('Jerry', 'Smith');
```

So the query should look like this:

```
WITH u1 AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        COALESCE(left(trim(first_name),1), '') ||
        COALESCE(replace(trim(last_name), ' ', '_'), '') as new_username
    FROM users
    ),
u2 AS (
    SELECT 
        id,
        new_username,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY new_username ORDER BY id) AS row
    FROM u1
    )
UPDATE users u
    SET username = new_username ||
        CASE WHEN u2.row > 1 THEN u2.row::varchar ELSE '' END
    FROM u2
    WHERE u.id = u2.id
```

Comment: Excellent catch

Comment: This was exactly it, discovered it right as you answered! The cascading CTE style for a DRY query is nice, I need to try and do that better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a WHERE condition in that update. (Not 100% sure on Postgres syntax)

```
WITH u2 AS 
  ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
             ( PARTITION BY first_name, last_name 
                   ORDER BY id ASC
             ) AS row, 
           first_name, 
           last_name 
      FROM users
  )
UPDATE users
  SET username = COALESCE(left(trim(u2.first_name),1), '')||COALESCE(replace(trim(u2.last_name), ' ', '_'), '')||(CASE WHEN u2.row > 1 THEN u2.row::varchar ELSE '' END)
  FROM u2
 WHERE first_name = u2.first_name
   AND last_name = u2.last_name;
```